# Saving user selected date as utc and query against db with utc fields

Tags: c#, timezone

I am a little bit confused what is the correct approach.

My app will be a global app meaning places (owners of events) with different timezones will be interacting with it and I want to keep things simple.

My app allows places(owner of events) to create events on a calendar (by obviously picking datetime) and then save to db.  (StartDateTime, EndDateTime)

Then users (event attendees) will view events happening near them.

What I have done so far is create 2 fields called StartDateTimeUTC, EndDateTimeUTC in my table and I have for each user allowed them to have a default timezoneid set.

When creating new events, i read their timezone, convert the datetime they have selected to UTC

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"); //gotten from db

DateTime startDateTimeUserSelected = new DateTime(2016, 4, 14, 2, 15, 0); //user picked from a datetimepicker
DateTime endDateTimeUserSelected = new DateTime(2016, 4, 14, 4, 15, 0); //user picked from a datetimepicker

var starDateTimeUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startDateTimeUserSelected, tz);
var endDateTimeUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(endDateTimeUserSelected, tz);
```

Then I save those to to my db fields, great now i got my user selected date as utc and saved to db.

Now I want to query the db for all events that happen today but I need to get the LOCAL TIME for the current user (based on their timezone)

```
 var currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz); //tz being read from db for particular user
```

And then I can use the currentTime to find and query my db for all events happening today.

**Just of the app**
Place creates events for their users (place can be anywhere in the world) using the backend, users using app on their mobile will view what events are happening at different places around them (same timezone)

**Question**
Is this the correct way to deal with timezones without having to worry about daylight savings? or do I have to do more for an app that shows events to user based on their local time, and keeping everything in sync.

or should i just store everything as none UTC and determine user's current datetime from browser for places (owner of events) to query against db, and edit/add events.   And determine users (attendees)'s time from the mobile device.

If I go with UTC i have keep track of timezone both for the Places and attendees and make sure all comparisons are done via UTC.

If i just enter everything as NONE utc, i dont have to worry about any conversion other than the fact that I need to read users CURRENT DATETIME from either browser/mobile device.

Have i missed anything?

Answer (score -1):

When I was working with Azure Table Storage (NOSQL) I encountered this same roadblock since ATS always store all date time fields as UTC.

On the database table I had 3 fields:

TerminalUtcTime DATETIME
TerminalTimezone CHAR(6)
TerminalLocalTime CHAR(12)

> The goal is to NEVER compute the terminal's local time using UTC and timezone. Because the effects of daylight
>   savings time (summer time), etc. is **not** reflected on the timezone as
>   well as UTC time.

On my experience, we had to forward the terminal's local time as is to some bank web service which is very strict. We had to send data as accurate as possible.

On the client:

```
DateTime terminalUtcTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
string terminalTimeZone = // Get from TimeZoneInfo.Local and format to ±hh:mm like +08:45 or -10:00 (format varies on how you may want it to be)
// Getting the timezone can be tricky because the hh and mm separator can be changed in the control panel so I had to use substrings instead
DateTime terminalLocalTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

On the server:

You just need to save the terminalUtcTime as TerminalUtcTime,
terminalTimezone as TerminalTimezone and the terminalLocalTime as string.

```
terminalLocalTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"); // Saves up to the milliseconds
```

Now, if needed, you can retrieve the DateTime instance of the terminal's local time. No need to compute, etc. I use DateTime.ParseExact(var, "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");

Yes, you have to add a new field on the table but it saves you all the worries. This is the approach on a database that only allows UTC time, but if you are using MySql, MSSQL, etc. that allows saving of non-UTC time then that may work for you as well and saves up all the trouble.

Comment: the terminal (server time) is never important for me keep track of, the only date I care about is the event date the user selected and then use that data to present events based off current date to the user so I am not sure if anything related to Local is of importance to me, unless I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: @Zoinky Why not filter the events to show on your app through country code of the client which for me makes more sense. So all clients in the same country will be viewing the same events with no care to the possible effects of daylight savings time and the like.